# Trouble serving Pyramid app with Nginx + uWSGI on AWS EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, pyramid, uwsgi

Having some issues with trying to serve pyramid app on a AWS EC2 instance where I can run nginx and when I attempt to access the site using the url provided by AWS, I can see the default web page of Nginx. However, when I attempt to serve pyramid app using the following command, the browser is still showing nginx web page instead of pyramid web page.

The command I used to serve the pyramid app after logging into AWS ssh is:

```
$ /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
```

My settings for **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen          <my.aws.ip.address>:80;
        server_name     <my.aws.url.address> <my.domain.address>;
        index           index.html index.htm index.py;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/<my.domain.address>.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/<my.domain.address.log>.error;
        root            /home/ec2-user/;
        charset         utf-8;

        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:3003;
            include     uwsgi_params;
        }

        location /static {
            root        /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/fruler/;
        }
    }

}
```

My settings for **/home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini**

```
###
# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.6-branch/narr/environment.html
###

[app:main]
use = egg:FRuler

pyramid.reload_templates = false
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 80

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.6-branch/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, fruler

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console

[logger_fruler]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = fruler

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s


[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3003
virtualenv = /home/ec2-user/env
die-on-term = 1
master = 1
logto = /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/uwsgi.log
pidfile = /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/pid_5000.pid
processes = 4

harakiri = 30
harakiri-verbose = true
limit-post = 5242880
post-buffering = 8192

mypaste = /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
paste = config:%(mypaste)
paste-logger = %(mypaste)
```

When I attempt to serve the pyramid app using:

```
$ /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
```

The pyramid default web page isn't showing and there is no command prompt thereafter.

Then I've also tried closing terminal window and when I attempted to relog into AWS through ssh and do the following command:

```
**$ ps ax | grep uwsgi**
31452 ?        S      0:00 /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
31463 ?        S      0:00 /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
31464 ?        S      0:00 /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
31465 ?        S      0:00 /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
31466 ?        S      0:00 /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
31502 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto uwsgi
```

Next, I attempt to look at /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/uwsgi.log

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Tue May  3 01:46:49 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) on 19 April 2016 04:32:58
os: Linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015
nodename: <aws.internal.ip.address>
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ec2-user
writing pidfile to /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/pid_5000.pid
detected binary path: /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
your processes number limit is 3824
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:3003 fd 3
Python version: 3.4.1 (default, Apr 19 2016, 02:22:12)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]
Set PythonHome to /home/ec2-user/env
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x12768f0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 404800 bytes (395 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Loading paste environment: config:/home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
ImportError: No module named 'paste.script'
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x12768f0 pid: 31509 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 31509)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 31513, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 31514, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 31515, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 31516, cores: 1)
```

We have tried this exact same setup on a dedicated web server with no issues ( pyramid default web page is showing ). However, when we attempted it on AWS, it isn't serving the default pyramid default page.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: These two lines in `uwsgi.log` look interesting:

```
Loading paste environment: config:/home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
ImportError: No module named 'paste.script'
```

Although I have no idea how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, we also have this issue with our dedicated server but it is still able to serve the pyramid app showing the default web page.

Comment: Most likely Nginx is not picking your configuration for the reasons that could include: bad IP definition, bad port definition, bad config file name, config file in a wrong folder

Comment: Till now, I'm not sure how aws work, but this config is exactly the same on our dedicated server and it's working perfectly fine.